# Несколько этапов регистрации с помощью Pjax

Tags: php, yii2, pjax

Доброго времени суток. Буквально только что разобрался с Pjax-ом, но теперь есть задача посложнее. Сейчас пробую реализовать регистрацию через Pjax, регистрация из 3 етапов, и у каждой есть своя страница с урлом и методом в контроллере.

Контоллер:

```
public function actionFirststep(){

if ($registrationForm->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

   return $this->redirect(['/usercabinet/registration/secondstep']);

   }
 return $this->render('index', ['model' => $registrationForm]);
}



public function actionSecondstep(){

if ($registrationForm->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

    return $this->redirect(['/usercabinet/registration/success']);

    }
 return $this->render('secondStep', ['model' => $registrationForm]);
}


public function actionSucces(){
   return $this->render('success');
}
```

Реально ли сделать такое Pjax-ом? Именно переход с первого етапа на второй(Со второго етапа на successs сложностей не возникает).

Comment: По моему Вы слишком мудрите. Что именно Вы хотите сделать?

Comment: Сделать регистрацию без перезагрузки страницы. Она у меня из 3 страниц состоит, спочатку поля e-mail и пароль, потом редиректится на страницу с дополнительными параметрами и затем редиректится на страницу success. Вот я хочу что бы вместо редиректов был ajax

Comment: Не надо так делать. Проще сделать одну форму в табах. При щелчке по "следующий шаг"(например), показываете следующую часть формы. В конце отправляете всё сразу. В итоге один контроллер, одно действие.

Comment: Тоже думал про такой вариант, но у меня 1 етап и 2 имеют дело с разнымы моделями: UserProfile(тут почта и пароль) и UserInfo(тут доп. инфа). Смогу ли я такое реализовать только с 1 запросом на сервер?

Comment: Ну и что, что разные модели. Можно использовать сколько угодно моделей в одном ActiveForm. Так же можно их обрабатывать все в одном контроллере/действии.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с несколькими действиями и контроллерами неверен.

В одном ActiveForm можно обработать несколько моделей.
Выглядит это так.

```
// Контроллер
public function actionCreate()
{
   $user = new User();
   $profile = new Profile();

   // тут обработка и запись в базу данных в разные таблицы.
   if($user->load(Yii::$app->post()) && $profile->load(Yii::$app->post())){
       $validData = $user->validate();
       $validData = $profile->validate() && $validData;
       if($validData){
          $user->save(false);
          $profile->save(false);
          return $this->redirect('success');
       }      
    }

   // подключение представления с формой.
   return $this->render('create', ['user' => $user, 'profile' => $profile);
}
```

В самом представлении с формой делаете так.

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin();

  echo $form->field('user', 'username')->textInput();
  echo $form->field('profile', 'address')->textInput();

ActiveForm::end();
```

Точно так же при обновлении записи. Две модели передаёте в этот же вид. Отправляете при помощи ajax(pjax).

Comment: Спасибо, на выходных буду пробовать переписать все.